# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://localhost/database/login.php

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am using Volley to connect to MySql database. I created the database tables and wrote the php function and below is the java code. All this was working all along but just yesterday it woke up giving this error in the logcat and its not returning any response, testing the php script using google chrome postman works just fine so im thinking there is something wrong in my java code.

BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.43.71/database/login.php

I know several questions like this have been asked before, i have gone through them all and nothing seems to work at all. I am going nuts.

```
private void login() {
      StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST, Constants.ACCOUNTLOGIN,
              loginSuccessListener(),
              loginErrorListener()) {
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
          Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
          params.put("user_phone_number", sPhoneNumber);
          params.put("user_password", sPassword);
          return params;
          };
      }; 
  mVolleyQueue.add(jsonObjRequest);
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

First check if you can open the same url on your mobile browser. I assume you use Apache2.4.9 webserver. If you've not changed default values for you get "denied permission". 
To solve this problem you need change some values in "httpd.conf" file which has Apache settings.

1- Under DocumentRoot change Directory xml tag as following:

```
<Directory />
     AllowOverride none
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2- Under "onlineoffline tag" update the line as following:

```
<Directory />
    ...
    ...
    ...
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note: If you use older version of Apache you need google for right syntax in httpd.conf

Let me know if this changes work or not. :)

Comment: Could you please provide some more information and perhaps error message? :-)

Answer (score 2):

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://localhost/database/login.php

Here is the problem in the URL, use your system IP where you hosted your web services and disable firewall, antivirus that may sometimes block to access your system services from other.

It may your IP address has changed, confirm it again. Service URL format would be something like http://your_system_ip_address/database/login.php

Comment: I have edited the question, by localhost i just meant my ip. The new url is the actual url that i am using. And i dont use any antivirus, no firewall

Comment: @HopewellMutanda make sure your system and device on which you are testing are on same network

Comment: I use wireless tithering and check and update the ip address each time i ran and test the app. I am sure they are on the same network

Comment: ok can you try to access your system in mobile Google chrome like http://your_system_ip_address/database/login.php  if this works then problem in code otherwise network issue.

Comment: So i tried what you said and i got this error Foebidden you dont have permission to access on this server

Comment: I glad its not a java error. So how do i go about it now

Comment: @HopewellMutanda Yup that is the error. some proxy or network problem, firewall, security of your system is not allowing to access your service. Call to network team to have a look!!

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

1. Internet permission in your android manifest file.
2. Check http://localhost/database/login.php on your system browser.

I think it will help.

Comment: Internet permission is there. I made sure of that

Comment: Had you check it on you system browser ?

Comment: Yes the system browser is the one i use for testing and its working fine. Its returning the correct responses

Answer (score 0):

Try it...
Go to XAMPP..
In Apache open file http-xampp.conf

comment this lines in the end...

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
# Require local
# ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#</LocationMatch>
```

save changes...
restart apache... !!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.
In `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`
change `Require local` o `require local` to `Require all granted`.

[Unexpected response code 403 for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738253/unexpected-response-code-403-for)

Answer (score -1):

I've got similar error to this one (400, instead of 403). Try do the following.

1. go to src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java
2. Change the following lines

   ```js
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
   ```

with

```js
 if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 405) {
     throw new IOException();
 }
```

Hope this helps.