# not getting parameters from php post request

Tags: php, android, mysql, wampserver

I'm having a weird problem that i couldn't find a solution for. I revisited an old code that worked in the past perfectly but now somehow it doesn't work properly.

The project is an android application connected with a database. I have a login activity where a post request going to be executed to check if the user exists in the database. The problem is somehow the parameters sent with the post request are not really sent.

Putting the android code apart i tried to test the post request separately. I'm using `wampserver 3.1.4` with `PHP 5.6.3`, `MySQL 5.7` and `Apache 2.4`. To retrieve the parameters from the post request i'm using this code snippet:

```
$username = null;
$password = null;

var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST['PARAM_EMAIL']))
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PARAM_EMAIL']);

if (isset($_POST['PARAM_PASSWORD']))
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['PARAM_PASSWORD']);
```

i used `postman` to test the request and `var_dump()` to check the content of the params.

Here an example of how i wrote the request and what result i got :

```
    http://192.168.2.103/GestionDesCamions/check.php?PARAM_EMAIL=user@xx.com&PARAM_PASSWORD=xx

<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>C:\wamp64\www\GestionDesCamions\check.php:12:</small>
    <b>array</b>
    <i>(size=0)</i>
    <i>
        <font color='#888a85'>empty</font>
    </i>
</pre>false
```

it says post request doesn't contain any params therefore i got in the end false because the user couldn't be found.

I used !empty() instead of isset() and i got the same result. I tested other requests, GET requests in particular and they work fine. Any idea how can i solve this problem ? I'm using windows 10 as an operating system.

**EDIT :**

here is the POST method i'm using in my android app :

```
public boolean SendToUrl(String strURL,
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        // Creer un buffer
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // Creer un client Http
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creer un obejet httppost pour utiliser la methode post
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
        try {
            // UrlEncodedFormEntit() : An entity composed of a list of
            // url-encoded pairs
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // recuperer la reponse
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            // recuperer le ack
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            // si ack =200 connexion avec succee
            if (statusCode == 200) {

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                // erreur du chargement
                Toast.makeText(_mContext, "pas de connexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(builder.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Try `$_GET` as you appear to be passing parameters on the querystring

Comment: well that worked ! but it's not working from the android app. A solution would be also to change it to GET request from the app too ! but i still don't understand why this is happening since post request worked fine in the past.. and if i'm not mistaken using POST request is the right thing to do by login ! or am i missing something ?

Comment: Does the Android app use POST or GET?

Comment: it uses POST ! i just edited my post with the POST method i'm using in my android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to approach this problem differently, i changed my android code a little and tried to send post requests with the library volley instead of what i used before and it throwed this error : `Unexpected response code 403 for "URL"`

After referring to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738253/unexpected-response-code-403-for) i found a solution which was simply to modify this document `httpd-vhosts.conf` in Apache as follows :

`require local` to `Require all granted`.

And now the POST requests are allowed and even the old code snippet for http requests works. Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem recently, I'm not sure when but sometime in the recent past when android sends a post request to php it arrives in the body. To get the post you have to use this to get it as a string then do what you will.

```
# Get JSON as a string 
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
# Get as an object 
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

Last app I made you could simply recieve the $_POST but this has changed.

Comment: I tried as you said but still didn't work. I found a solution and i just posted it. The problem was with wampserver