# Android : E/Volley: [3347] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://172.18.0.200/test.php

Tags: php, android, connection

I want to connect `Android` application to remote server. But i am getting this error

> E/Volley: [3347] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://172.18.0.200/test.php

Server is a local laptop `172.18.0.200` (`PHP` script is running with `WAMP`)and client is a computer system (Android Studio).

**Singleton class code**

```
package com.check;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context){
        mCtx=context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(requestQueue==null){
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;

    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getmInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance==null){
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void addRequestQueue(Request request ){
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

**Main Activity Class code**

```
package com.check;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView name,email;
    String serverAdress = "http://172.18.0.200/test.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            StringRequest Srequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverAdress, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(0);
                        String code = jo.getString("code");
                        String message = jo.getString("message");

                        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        name.setText(jo.getString("code"));
                        email.setText(jo.getString("message"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addRequestQueue(Srequest);
        }
    }
```

**PHP Code on server**

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $result = array();
    echo("<br>");

        $code = "Login Failed";
        $message = "User NOT fOUND...Try again";
        array_push($result,array("code"=>$code,"message"=> $message);
        echo json_encode($result);

    ?>
```

I have read this [Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643765/basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-403-for-http-localhost-d) but not gives any solution.

Comment: Have you tried to access the url with Postman or any other tool? Is it working fine on that?

Comment: @RahulVats Not complete `URL` but only `ip`. I `ping` to laptop's `IP` using cmd. Ping is working.

Comment: Is your mobile and your laptop connected to the same wifi network?

Comment: @SripadRaj I think Yes! My virtual device for android is my mobile (real device) and this mobile is connected to the same WIFI as my laptop is connected.

Comment: @Amar please first check your post request through postman and check results. If you need to read about post man search over internet or let me know in case you need any help.

Comment: @RahulVats Is there some other way of doing it?

Comment: @Amar You can check your your webservice through post man chrome extension. For how to use you can follow: http://www.iminfo.in/post/post-json-postman-rest-client-chrome. or video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBjXVrS8nXs